# Practical usage of .Single(), .SingleOrDefault() methods

Tags: c#

I often come across in our project with non-informative messages like "sequence contains more than one element". It happens from time to time.

Isn't it better to check:

```
var count = collection.Count(i => predicate);
if (count > 1)
{
   throw new InformativeException("...");
}

if (count == 0)
{
    throw new AnotherInformativeException("...");
}
```

?

I really don't understand in what cases Single()/SingleOrDefault() may be useful. Only if you will catch the InvalidOperationException and try to convert it to a more informative.

Comment: Single is ideal when there must only be ever at most one matching value, e.g. a check for unique Id - if there are two values in a list with the same "unique" ID, then things are broken and I want Single to throw and tell me so.

Comment: For an overview over `Single()` etc. you can take a look at the [`LINQ` documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/329/first-firstordefault-last-lastordefault-single-and-singleordefault#t=201609071055283913178)

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the error messages are generic and not very specific. However, I argue that they don't *need* to be:

There are two cases:

1. It is reasonably possible that there are `<> 1` elements (for example, due to an invalid configuration file entry or an unlikely user input error). In that case, checking the number of items in the list and throwing an informative exception is the right thing to do.
2. It is not reasonably possible that there are `<> 1` elements - i.e., if you get `<> 1` elements here, you have made a programming error somewhere else. Example:

   ```
   // getItem's documentation guarantees that each element has a unique ID and
   // that there is an element with ID 1.
   var myItems = getItems();

   // if this fails, there is an implementation error in getItems
   var item1 = myItems.Single(x => x.ID == 1);
   ```

   In such cases, the default error message is usually sufficient. Using `Single` here basically acts as a run-time assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Single and SingleOrDefault() can be used in the following scenrarios:

- [Single()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a single element to be found in the matching sequence you are using.
  It does throw an expection if sequence is empty or contains more than one element.
- [SingleOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx) does not throw an exception when matching sequence is empty (and return detault, usually `null`), but does throw an exception when matching sequence contains more than one element.

You can also use the following LINQ functions:

- [Count()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx) to check for a greater values (e.g. > 1)
- [Any()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns true is mathicng sequence contains one or more items.

Answer (score 0):

`Single` and `SingleOrDefault` should be used when you expect one and only one, or one or none (respectively).

You could do it the way you suggest with by checking counts explicitly (which is the traditional method for such things), but sometimes the code can be more concise and/or easier to follow when you let LINQ throw the exception for you:

```
try {

    // a bunch of stuff

    var x = y.Where(z => z.ID = id).Single();

    // more stuff

} catch (SomeException e) {
    // other expected issue 
} catch (OtherException e) {
    // other expected issue 
} catch (InvalidOperationException e) {
    // how'd we wind up with more (or less) than 1???
} catch (Exception e) {
    // unexpected issue
}
```

Some (myself included) might prefer to have that peripheral validation code (which is essentially what the above represents) out of the way of the main logic block.  Note that this does not loose sight of the main logic requirement, as `Single()` plainly tells us that we expect one and only one item, so there's no loss of knowledge by moving the count validation to an exception handler.

I do wish that it threw a more specific exception than `InvalidOperationException` though... that's pretty generic.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following pattern if I expect **exactly one** element:

```
try {
    var singleElement = x.SingleOrDefault(x => /* some expression */);
}
catch (InvalidOperationException iopex) {
   throw new InformativeException("More than one element found.");
}
if (singleElement == null) {
   throw new InformativeException("No element found.");
}
// work with singleElement from here
```

Comment: You are using exceptions to handle something that can easily be checked without.

Comment: True, but if the exception is catched this is a hint to a bug in the code, as we expect to retrieve zero or one element. Because the exception should never occur during normal operation, I think working with exception handling is appropriate.